# NSSuperscriptAttributeName show error?

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-text

I am trying to create a subscripted text in iphone using NSMutableAttributedString. But the "NSSuperscriptAttributeName" show some error " undeclared identifier ".  How can i solve it?

```
NSDictionary * superscriptAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] 
                                                                  forKey:NSSuperscriptAttributeName];
    NSAttributedString * st = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"st"
                                                              attributes:superscriptAttrs];
```

Comment: Was my answer of any use to you?

Comment: No. it couldn't work with kCTSuperscriptAttributeName.

Comment: Please see my answer. i hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707747/how-to-append-the-following-characters-as-superscript-to-nsstring-in-ios/16708087#16708087

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're on iOS, you need to use a different set of constants which you can find [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_StringAttributes_Ref/Reference/reference.html).

In your case `NSSuperscrptAttributeName` should be `kCTSuperscriptAttributeName`.

Comment: Don't forget that he'll need to import CoreText framework and do `#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>` in the class.

Comment: Your links appear backwards.  That's the link to the Mac constants, not the iOS constants.  If it works, then why does it work since this is info for the wrong platform.

Comment: @AlexZavatone This no longer applies, using `NSSuperscriptAttributeName` is now fine on iOS.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed.  How do we close this thread as it provides misleading onto now.