# How to append the following characters ‡, †, * as superscript to NSString in iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, nsstring

I need append the following  characters `‡, †, *` as superscript  to `NSString` in `iOS` . Need your help. I use the following [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Punctuation_(Unicode_block)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Punctuation_%28Unicode_block%29) link but they are appending to `NSString` , But i want them as superscript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use this one. And you need to #import `<CoreText/CTStringAttributes.h>`. This code works only in iOS6 or later version.

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 40)];
NSString *infoString=@"X2 and H20 A‡ B† C*";

NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:infoString];

[attString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@1 range:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@-1 range:NSMakeRange(8, 1)];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@1 range:NSMakeRange(12, 1)];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@1 range:NSMakeRange(15, 1)];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@1 range:NSMakeRange(18, 1)];

lbl.attributedText = attString;

[self.view addSubview:lbl];
```

**Output**

[image]

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

`NSString` does not allow you to format specific parts of the text. If you're planning to display your text in a `UILabel`, `UITextField`, or `UITextView` (and your app doesn't have to run on anything below iOS 6), you can use `NSAttributedString` and apply a `kCTSuperscriptAttributeName` attribute with the value `@1`. If you're using a `UIWebView`, use HTML's `<sup>` element.

Comment: But they are unicode characters how can i do that . Each time i had to   do appending , so if any unicode character for superscript of these is available then it will be highly appreciable

Comment: There is no Unicode character for a superscript dagger or double dagger, and the only Unicode superscript asterisk is combining (it overlaps another character). The only way to do what you want to do is by inserting a normal character and using either HTML or NSAttributedString to make it superscript. If you're currently building up an NSMutableString by appending to it, you can probably convert your code to use NSMutableAttributedString without much difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could achieve that:

```
NSString *string = @"abcdefghi";

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];

NSInteger num1 = 1;
CFNumberRef num2 = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberNSIntegerType, &num1);

[attrString addAttribute:(id)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:(id)CFBridgingRelease(num2) range:NSMakeRange(6, 3)];

self.label.attributedText = attrString;
```

, where label is a UILabel property already added to the UI.

Make sure you add first the CoreText framework, also add this line on top of you .m file.

Hope it helps you somehow

Comment: NSNumber and CFNumber are toll-free bridged, so there's no reason to create a CFNumber here and deal with Core Foundation's memory management when an NSNumber would do.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

Step 1.

```
    import CoreText
```

Step 2.

```
    let range1 = NSMakeRange(1, 1)
    let range2 = NSMakeRange(5, 1)

    let mutableStr : NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "h20 x2")
    mutableStr.addAttribute(kCTSuperscriptAttributeName as String, value:-1, range: range1)
    mutableStr.addAttribute(kCTSuperscriptAttributeName as String, value:1, range: range2)

    self.lbl.attributedText = mutableStr
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This has stopped working since iOS 10.3 for me. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Might be they changed method nothing changed in logic, so you can modify it little bit.